# Script to move specific files from one folder to another

Tags: linux

Linux script to move all *.zip files from yesterday's folder to today's folder where folder name is like yyyymmdd. Ex: 20150609

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
FOLDER_YESTERDAY=`date +%Y%m%d --date=yesterday`
FOLDER_TODAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
mkdir -p "${FOLDER_TODAY}"
mv "${FOLDER_YESTERDAY}/*.zip" "${FOLDER_TODAY}/"
```

Tested on CentOS 6.6 only.